# Free shipping on specific shipping method

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, shipping-methods, free-shipping

I'd like to offer my customers free shipping when the cart is over $65 but only in 1 specific shipping method.

I have 4 shipping methods but only one should be free.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I'm using Community Edition 1.9.0.1

Comment: may be this link help you http://www.lexiconn.com/blog/2015/01/magento-tip-setting-up-free-shipping/

Comment: create shopping cart rule for the particular shipping method.

Comment: @Abdul I'm trying to do it with a shopping cart rule but i can't do it work. In conditions I've created the condition "Shipping Method is [shipping method]" but in chekout all the shipping methods seems to be free.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting a specific shipping method under Free Method in `System -> Configuration -> Shipping Methods` and expanding your shipping method of choice. Then, expand all other shipping methods and make sure "Free Method" is set to "none". Ensure this option hasn't also been set in another scope.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Follow bellow steps

**Step : 1**

Go admin side `Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules` create new rules to free shipping apply to particular order amount for the login customer

**Step : 2** Follow bellow screen shot for condition

[image] 
[image]
[image]

**Step : 3** Check frontend

[image]

Note : Above example to shipping method **Flat Rate** pls set your shipping method to above code & order subtotal

Comment: Thanks @Abdul but still not working for me :(

Comment: what is issue ?Which shipping method are need to free?

Comment: I've got 2 shipping methods, flat rate and table rates.

I want to make free the flat one, when some conditions are ok.

But the 2 methos are free when the conditions are ok and i don't know why

Comment: open file app\code\core\Mage\Shipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate.php

Comment: and add code bellow code

if($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() > 65) {
    $shippingPrice = '0.00';
   }

Comment: after 

if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $this->getFreeBoxes()) {
                $shippingPrice = '0.00';
            }

Comment: but... that will be ok if i want the free option for orders>65$, but if i want more options? it is only possible to do this in code? not at Shopping Cart Price Rules?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I found a solution inspired by the [Abdul comment](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97188/free-shipping-on-specific-shipping-method#comment131559_97546)

**The Problem**: Multistore website with multiple shipping method: flatrate, matrixrate. In some store the free shipping rule should be applied only to matrixrate and not flatrate, in some others should be applied to flatrate.

**The Solution**: Use the rule like explaned [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97546/4647) with whatever condition but the shipping method one. Then create a module that extend the Flatrate model (or the one witch shouldn't be affected by the rule) for prevent to apply the shipping rule according to a configuration specific for website.

Adding the configuration file (`system.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <carriers>
            <groups>
                <flatrate>
                    <fields>
                        <ignore_freeshipping translate="label">
                            <label>Ignore Free Shipping Promotions</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </ignore_freeshipping>
                    </fields>
                </flatrate>
            </groups>
        </carriers>
    </sections>
</config>
```

The Flatrate model rewrite:

```
<?php

class Ac_Freeshipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrate extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrate
{
    /**
     * rewrite original method, with condition to freeshipping
     *
     * @param Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $data
     * @return Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result
     */
    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $freeBoxes = 0;
        if ($request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {

                if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                            $freeBoxes += $item->getQty() * $child->getQty();
                        }
                    }
                  ////////////HERE I CHECK IF THE CONFIGURATION IS SET FOR SKIP FREE SHIPPING RULES
                } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping() && !Mage::helper('ac_freeshipping')->flatrateIgnoreFreeShipping()) {
                    $freeBoxes += $item->getQty();
                }
            }
        }
        $this->setFreeBoxes($freeBoxes);

        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        if ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'O') { // per order
            $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
        } elseif ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'I') { // per item
            $shippingPrice = ($request->getPackageQty() * $this->getConfigData('price')) - ($this->getFreeBoxes() * $this->getConfigData('price'));
        } else {
            $shippingPrice = false;
        }

        $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($shippingPrice);

        if ($shippingPrice !== false) {
            $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

            $method->setCarrier('flatrate');
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod('flatrate');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            ////////////HERE I CHECK IF THE CONFIGURATION IS SET FOR SKIP FREE SHIPPING RULES
            if (($request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $this->getFreeBoxes()) && !Mage::helper('ac_freeshipping')->flatrateIgnoreFreeShipping()) {
                $shippingPrice = '0.00';
            }


            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

            $result->append($method);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

The complete module is here: https://github.com/andreacanton/magento-freeshipping-rule